# I need to add a new font in my java project

Tags: java, fonts, project

I have a project in Java Apache netbeans IDE 15, I am using Java With ant without creating the Main.

I already have my poppins-bold.ttf file, I just don't know how to add it to my project to be able to use it, I hope your help, thank you very much <3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVoam.png)

I have not tried much yet, I have not found material that is useful to me

Comment: [Load your font file as a resource](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, you can load the `Poppins-Bold.ttf` file (or any file) for use from a **resource** directory (folder) attached to your Project's classpath. Below are images that demonstrate where you might create a resources directory:

**What it would look like in the Project Pane of your IDE:**

[image]

**What it would look like in the your File Explorer application:**

[image]

It's important where you create this **resources** directory so that sub-directories (if any) and files within it can be be acquired when your application is run from either the IDE or a distributive **.jar** file. As you can see, the `Poppins-Bold.ttf` is contained directly within the **resources** directory (source package) for this demo.

Once your `Poppins-Bold.ttf` Font file has been saved to resources, you can load it for use in many different ways. Here is a method that can do the job in both your IDE or when your application is a distributive **.jar** file. Read the comments in code:

```
/**
 * Loads a Font from resources and returns a Font Object.This method will 
 * load a font from resources whether your code is run from your IDE or run 
 * from an distributive <b>.jar</b> file.
 * 
 * @param theClass (Class) The application's main class, for example:<pre>
 * {@code 
 * 
 *   String fontName = "Poppins-Bold.ttf";
 *   float fontSize = 24f;
 *   
 *   // Load the desired font file from resources and create a Font object.
 *   Font font = loadFontFromResource(MyMainClassName.class, fontName, fontSize);
 * }</pre>
 * 
 * @param fontFileName (String) The file name of the Font file contained 
 * within the resources directory, for example: <b>"Poppins-Bold.ttf"</b>. 
 * Only the Font file name (with file name extension) is expected.<br>
 * 
 * @param fontSize (float) The desired size of the font that is loading in. 
 * If any value less than 1 is supplied then the font size will default to 
 * 12.0f.<br>
 * 
 * @return (Font Object)
 */
public static Font loadFontFromResource(Class theClass, String fontFileName, float fontSize) {
    float fntSize = 12f;  // Default font size:
    /* If the supplied font size is greater than 1 then 
       make it the supplied size otherwise leave it at 
       default:        */
    if (fontSize >= 1f) {
        fntSize = fontSize;
    }
    
    // Load in the supplied font file from resources.
    InputStream is = theClass.getResourceAsStream("/resources/" + fontFileName);
    Font font = null;
    try {
        /* Creates a new Font using the specified font type and input data. 
           The new Font is created with a point size of 1 and style PLAIN. 
           This base font can then be used with the deriveFont methods in 
           this class to derive new Font objects with varying sizes, styles, 
           transforms and font features.            */
        font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
        font = font.deriveFont(fntSize);
    }
    catch (FontFormatException | IOException ex) {
        // Display Exceptions if any:
        System.err.println("Error Loading Font (" + fontFileName 
                         + ")! Here is why:\n" + ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        /* Close the InputStream if it's open. Font.createFont() does
           not close the InputStream:            */
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }
    return font;
}
```

Below is a complete runnable demo application which demonstrates the above in real action. Again, read the comments in code:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class LoadFontDemo {
    
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel label; 

    
    // Constructor:
    public LoadFontDemo() {
        // Create demo GUI:
        initForm();
    }
    
    // Application entry startup method:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // App started this way to avoid the need for statics unless wanted.
        new LoadFontDemo().startApp(args);
    }
    
    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        // Display the Demo GUI:
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            frame.setVisible(true);
            
            // Center the JFrame window to center screen.
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        });
    }
    
    // Create GUI:
    private void initForm() {
        // Desired font info
        String fontName = "Poppins-Bold.ttf";   // The font name to load.
        float fontSize = 24f;                   // The desired font size.
        
        // Load the desired font file from resources and create a Font object.
        Font font = loadFontFromResource(LoadFontDemo.class, fontName, fontSize);

        // Create a small Font Display GUI demo:
        frame = new JFrame("Font Load/Use Demo");
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 150));
        
        // The JLabel the loaded font will be demonstrated in:
        label = new JLabel("The \"" + fontName + "\" font demo.");
        label.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 120));
        label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        if (font != null) {
            label.setFont(font);
        }
        
        panel.add(label);               // Add JLabel to JPanel.
        frame.setContentPane(panel);    // Set JPanel to JFrame Content Pane.
        frame.pack();                   // Pack the JFrame.
    }
    
        
    /**
     * Loads a Font from resources and returns a Font Object.This method will 
     * load a font from resources whether your code is run from your IDE or run 
     * from an distributive <b>.jar</b> file.
     * 
     * @param theClass (Class) The application's main class, for example:<pre>
     * {@code 
     * 
     *   String fontName = "Poppins-Bold.ttf";
     *   float fontSize = 24f;
     *   
     *   // Load the desired font file from resources and create a Font object.
     *   Font font = loadFontFromResource(MyMainClassName.class, fontName, fontSize);
     * }</pre>
     * 
     * @param fontFileName (String) The file name of the Font file contained 
     * within the resources directory, for example: <b>"Poppins-Bold.ttf"</b>. 
     * Only the Font file name (with file name extension) is expected.<br>
     * 
     * @param fontSize (float) The desired size of the font that is loading in. 
     * If any value less than 1 is supplied then the font size will default to 
     * 12.0f.<br>
     * 
     * @return (Font Object)
     */
    public static Font loadFontFromResource(Class theClass, String fontFileName, float fontSize) {
        float fntSize = 12f;  // Default font size:
        /* If the supplied font size is greater than 1 then 
           make it the supplied size otherwise leave it at 
           default:        */
        if (fontSize >= 1f) {
            fntSize = fontSize;
        }
        
        // Load in the supplied font file from resources.
        InputStream is = theClass.getResourceAsStream("/resources/" + fontFileName);
        Font font = null;
        try {
            /* Creates a new Font using the specified font type and input data. 
               The new Font is created with a point size of 1 and style PLAIN. 
               This base font can then be used with the deriveFont methods in 
               this class to derive new Font objects with varying sizes, styles, 
               transforms and font features.            */
            font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
            font = font.deriveFont(fntSize);
        }
        catch (FontFormatException | IOException ex) {
            // Display Exceptions if any:
            System.err.println("Error Loading Font (" + fontFileName 
                             + ")! Here is why:\n" + ex.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            /* Close the InputStream if it's open. Font.createFont() does
               not close the InputStream:            */
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                }
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.err.println(ex);
                }
            }
        }
        return font;
    }
}
```